# grid shortcode with classes

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create shortcodes from the Bootstrap 3 grid.
So far I have my basic shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('col_lg_12', 'col_lg_12' );
function col_lg_12( $atts, $content = null ) {
return '<div class="col-lg-12">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
```

This works well, but I have to set this for all columns. Not a problem but I think it could be better.

Beside that, in normal HTML I can give a row or column an extra class like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 custom-class"></div>
</div>
```

With my shortcode, that's impossible.
How can i do this?

Regards,

Roland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look to do this with shortcode parameters.

So your shortcode might look like:

```
[columns amount='12' classes='class-1 class-2']text[/columns]
```

Code might look as follows (untested):

```
function columns_function( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'amount' => 12,
        'classes' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    return '<div class="col-lg-' . $amount . ' ' . $classes . '"' . do_shortcode($content). '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'columns', 'columns_function' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. You've put me in the right direction with the array. Got it now.